# Select2 dropdown does not stay open when the bottom of the options block extends below the browser window

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

When the bottom of the options box extends below the browser window, the options block does not stay open when clicked unless your mouse happens to be hovering over the box's scroll bar. If you click in the middle of the dropdown menu, it just snaps back up immediately, selecting whatever your house happens to have been hovering over. You can see what I am talking about here: http://what-key-am-i-in.herokuapp.com/ and click on the 'fretBoard' link, then try to change the dropdown showing keys (lower left dropdown menu) with the bottom of your browser window only slightly below where the menu is.

Shouldn't the menu open upwards instead? Thanks!

Comment: Yikes. Took a look and nothing looks out of place initially, but it's definitely reproducible. You might try asking in Select2's Github issues.

Comment: Thanks, I opened an issue here: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/2299 if you want to follow along.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was fixed in the Select2 repo. https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/2620/commits

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, I added `overflow: visible` to the CSS for that select box and it cured the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS solved it for me

```
.select2-search--dropdown.select2-search--hide {
  display: contents;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```